# get unique combination values of a correlation matrix - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

Let's suppose I have a correlation matrix that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,0.2,0.3,0.4],'b':[0.2,1,0.5,0.6],'c':[0.3,0.5,1,0.7],'d':[0.4,0.6,0.7,1]}, index=['a','b','c','d'])
```

what is the best way to extract the unique values of each pairwise combination (a-b, a-c, etc)?

```
df2 =
      a_b  a_c  a_d  b_c  b_d  c_d 
      0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
```

the only way I see doing this is to write my own function, but was wondering if someone knows a shortcut for this

Comment: in one line, to get just the correlations, it's `df.values[np.triu_indices(len(df), 1)]`. this assumes `df` is a square dataframe of correlations. see my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df_out = df.stack()
df_out.index = df_out.index.map('_'.join)
df_out = df_out.to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
   a_a  a_b  a_c  a_d  b_a  b_b  b_c  b_d  c_a  c_b  c_c  c_d  d_a  d_b  d_c  
0  1.0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.2  1.0  0.5  0.6  0.3  0.5  1.0  0.7  0.4  0.6  0.7
```

And, if you want to get rid of a_a, b_b, etc..

```
df_out = df.stack()
df_out = df_out[df_out.index.get_level_values(0) != df_out.index.get_level_values(1)]
df_out.index = df_out.index.map('_'.join)
df_out = df_out.to_frame().T
```

Output

```
   a_b  a_c  a_d  b_a  b_c  b_d  c_a  c_b  c_d  d_a  d_b  d_c
0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.2  0.5  0.6  0.3  0.5  0.7  0.4  0.6  0.7
```

Or to get rid of b_a and keep a_b:

```
df_out = df.stack()
df_out = df_out[df_out.index.get_level_values(0) < df_out.index.get_level_values(1)]
df_out.index = df_out.index.map('_'.join)
df_out = df_out.to_frame().T
```

Or combining a few lines using lambda function in `.loc`:

```
df_out = df.stack().loc[lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(0) < x.index.get_level_values(1)]
df_out.index = df_out.index.map('_'.join)
df_out = df_out.to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
   a_b  a_c  a_d  b_c  b_d  c_d
0  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! I knew that there would be a more elegant way to do this than writing my own function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you can play with indexes

```
df2 = df.unstack().reset_index()
s = df2[['level_0', 'level_1']].agg(frozenset,1).drop_duplicates()
df2 = df2.loc[s.index]
ind = df2.agg(lambda k:  (k['level_0']+'_'+k['level_1']), axis=1)
df2.set_index(ind)[0].to_frame().T

    a_a a_b a_c a_d b_b b_c b_d c_c c_d d_d
0   1.0 0.2 0.3 0.4 1.0 0.5 0.6 1.0 0.7 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use matrix effectively:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,0.2,0.3,0.4],'b':[0.2,1,0.5,0.6],'c':[0.3,0.5,1,0.7],'d':[0.4,0.6,0.7,1]}, index=['a','b','c','d'])
unique_values=[s for s in np.tril(df, k=-1).flatten() if s!=0]
print(unique_values)
```

It gives you: `[0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7]`

The key is the [np.tril](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

if the correlations are `corrs` (e.g from `corrs = df.corr()`), then the unique correlation values are:

```
upper_right_entries = np.triu_indices(len(corrs), 1)
corrs.values[upper_right_entries]
```

this uses `numpy.triu_indices`, which produces a list of indices to fetch all upper right entries for a 2-d array. the `1` argument excludes the main diagonal (which in a correlation matrix, is `1.0`).

h/t to @Ji Ma for his answer using `np.tril`. my solution is shorter and easier to understand, i think.